# Absolutely positioned div background-size:cover not working

Tags: html, css

I have a division with class popOver.

**CSS**

```
.popOver {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    right: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 100px;
    background-size: cover;
    background:url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200');
}
```

This does not result as expected. `background-size: cover` does not seam to have any effect, why is it so?

**Here is the fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/ksLd13y8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the `background-size` property is being overwritten by the `background` property set *after* it. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size):

> If the value of this property is not set in a `background` shorthand property that is applied to the element after the `background-size` CSS property, the value of this property is then reset to its initial value by the shorthand property.

Here are three options:

- Set the `background-size` property *after* the `background` property:

  [**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vzo380jh/)

  ```
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200');
  background-size: cover;
  ```
- Use the property `background-image` to set the background image rather than the `background` shorthand property:

  [**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/z4juqvz0/)

  ```
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200');
  ```
- Or use the shorthand to set both properties:

  [**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/oLyuq91p/)

  ```
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200') 0 0 / cover;
  ```